# Do you have any information if the completely monotonic function of n-variables has been defined yet?

Tags: special-functions

Do you have any information if the completely monotonic function of $n$-variables function has been defined yet?

Comment: Have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2449 -- it lists many references too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like to look into [Ressel paper here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11117-013-0244-6). If you don't have access then check out his [presentation slides](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/positivity2013/presentations/ressel.pdf).